# Im getting a typeError saying Im passing a string but my list is an int

Tags: python, sorting, typeerror

i need help in the sorting part .I can tunderstand why isnt it getting sorted after slicing and also after mapping th list to int its giveing the same error pls help me out

````
def ele(arr):
    for i in range(1,len(arr)-1):
        k=i-1
        l=i+1
        m=0
        a=[]*0
        b=[]*0
        print(*arr)
        if(k!=0):
            a=arr[-1:k]
            a=list(map(int,a))
            a.sort(reverse="True")
            print(*a)
        else:
            a.append(arr[k])
        #print(*a)
        if(l!=len(arr)-1):
            b=arr[l:]
            b=list(map(int,b))
            b.sort(reverse="True")
            print(*b)
        else:
            b.append(arr[l])
        if(b[0]<arr[i] and arr[i]>a[0]):
            m=1
            print(arr[i])
            break
    if(m==0):
        print(-1)
t=int(input())
for i in range(0,t):
    n=int(input())
    arr=list(map(int,input().split()))
    ele(arr)
    ```

 File "main.py", line 28, in ele                                                              
    b.sort(reverse="True")                                                                     
TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)
````

Comment: `b.sort(reverse=True)`

Comment: it would perhaps be more helpful for the novice if it said `TypeError: a boolean is required (got type str)` but bools are ints anyway

Comment: curiously, reverse does actually accept any integer it would seem, e.g. `lst.sort(reverse=3)`-- i'm surprised is does not accept bools only?

Comment: Also, to state the obvious (in case either @Chris_Rands or the OP missed it), `a.sort(reverse="True")` also needs to be changed to `a.sort(reverse=True)`

Answer (score 1):

The reverse parameter is a boolean parameter, you should use `True` instead of `"True"`

```
def ele(arr):
    for i in range(1,len(arr)-1):
        k=i-1
        l=i+1
        m=0
        a=[]*0
        b=[]*0
        print(*arr)
        if(k!=0):
            a=arr[-1:k]
            a=list(map(int,a))
            a.sort(reverse=True)
            print(*a)
        else:
            a.append(arr[k])
        #print(*a)
        if(l!=len(arr)-1):
            b=arr[l:]
            b=list(map(int,b))
            b.sort(reverse=True)
            print(*b)
        else:
            b.append(arr[l])
        if(b[0]<arr[i] and arr[i]>a[0]):
            m=1
            print(arr[i])
            break
        if(m==0): # <-- this should be indented too
            print(-1)
t=int(input())
for i in range(0,t):
    n=int(input())
    arr=list(map(int,input().split()))
    ele(arr)
```